# Show name of selected parent in view listing children

Tags: sapui5

I have a parent - child relationship in a JSON model. I have a view that lists the parents using an ObjectList. The press event of an item in this list navigates to another view where a similar ObjectList shows the children of the selected parent.

I want to be able to make the title of the view displaying the children include an attribute of the parent. For example, if the model is:

```
{
    "parents": [
        {
        "name": "Spartacus","children": [{"name": "Spartacus Jnr"}, {"name": "Little Spartacus"}]
        }, 
        {"name": "Rasputin", "children": [{"name": "Grigori"}, {"name": "Yefimovich"}]
        }, 
        {"name": "Sting", "children": [{"name": "Josepth"}, {"name": "Fuchsia"}]}
            ]
}
```

Then if I select parent 'Spartacus' then the view showing the children should have as a title `Children of Spartacus`.

Important: For various reasons I have the child view bound to the children array. If I bound the child view to the parent and set the ObjectList path to `/children` then this would solve my problem. I could also get the path for the objectContext of the view and chop it up and retrieve the parent value that way - but that feels clunky and anyway I use XML view declaration. Overall I am stubborn and curious and want to know about upward traversal using relative paths.

I have tried a relative path approach using double-dots as one would in, for example, xpath:

```
headerText="Children of {../name}"
```

But this does not work. I have found much to explain bindings in UI5 but nothing discussing traversing up the model as is required here. Can anyone help with a solution or a link to docs that give a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default JSONBinding implementation does not support path traversal. However it is possible to easily solve your issue, by setting a different binding context where it is needed. I created an [example](https://jsbin.com/fomoxad/edit?html,output) simulating this. The items aggregation of the list containing the children is directly bound to the children array:

```
let path = "/parents/0";
let childrenTable = this.byId("children");
childrenTable.bindAggregation("items", {
    "path" : path + "/children",
    "template" : new StandardListItem({ "title" : "{name}"})
});
```

To show the name of the parent, I added a toolbar to the list and bind it to the corresponding parent in the model.

```
childrenTable.getAggregation("headerToolbar").bindElement(path);
```

Comment: Ok thanks for another useful technique. I am mildly surprised UI5 offers no easier method because this has to be a common pattern. Also it dilutes the power of the declarative XML view approach to some extent.

Comment: I would set the binding context of the view showing the children to the parent instead of the children array. I do not know if other frameworks support this, but UI5 is flexible enough to plug in your own binding syntax. ;)

Answer (score 1):

If this were OData you could have a link to the parent inside the child objects and refer to it through that but as far as I am aware, there is no upwards relationship like this for a JSONModel.

You have really answered your own question here. What you want to do is bind the view to the parent and reference the children with the relative path. I don't see this as chunky. What is the disadvantage? You would still be loading the same data in the model and it is still organised in a logical fashion.

In fact, (to diverge a little) loading an oDataModel like I have mentioned above would be adding repeated values to the model with no obvious advantage when the view could have just been bound differently.

Comment: Thanks - the question was contrived to give the need for an upward traversal in a JSON model. One thing to pick up on is that I am using a List control which AFAIK has one binding opportunity which I use to bind to the children array of the model. But I cannot bind the LIst.headerText to something else - this was the reason for the upward traversal requirement.  It is also why Matbtt in his answer has used a separate text field as a header.  Thanks for your thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

My own workaround is to contrive to get the parent name in the controller for the children view, then use

```
var list = this.byId("ChldrenList")
list.setHeaderText('Children for ' + mdlParent.name)  
// where mdlParent.name is my arbitrary model and attribute to be displayed.
```

I remain unhappy with this as it dilutes the power of the declarative XML view approach. But my boss says to suck it up and move on 8-)